# Connection is not stable in Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using socket.io to build an application to share some html objects to all users connected to a room. But the users get disconnected automatically after some time. I would like to know how socket.io provides stable connection between server and connected user.

Comment: Show some back-end code and try being less abstract, try finding a problem that persists and we can replicate.

Comment: thank you for the question.

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect may occur for several reasons, starting from network failures and ending with rather specific issues regarding load balancers. Here we cannot say we'll have 100% stable connection any time, some disconnects may occur in time to time.

If you happen to have disconnects, your app should know how to handle them. At first, you have to monitor `disconnect`, `reconnect`, `reconnect_attempt` and `reconnect_failed` events on client side (read [events](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/)) and ensure you are able to rejoin the room correctly  after they were fired. There shouldn't be any additional code on server side unless you have to do something special on `disconnect`, for example, to delete a user from users array of some sort.